# Convert digest (Unsigned char*) to its value as int in C

Tags: python, c, string, integer, char

I’m using SHA512 to get the digest of some message. I want to convert the digest into int (possible int with 512 bits). I write the code, but I notice that I always get 0 as answer.I write code both in python and in c, in python it much easier.

This is my code in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <OpenSSL/sha.h>

int main() {
    unsigned char message[] = "hello world";
    unsigned char digest[512];
    SHA512(message,strlen((char *) message),digest);
    int integer_value = atoi((char *) digest);
    printf("The integer value of the message is %d\n", integer_value);
    return 0;
}
```

In python it is much easier, and it’s working fine!

```
import hashlib
import sys 

Message ="hello world"
integer_value = int.from_bytes(hashlib.sha512(Message.encode()).digest(),sys.byteorder)
```

I’m new in C, I think all day to about idea to solve it, but in C there are so many things to do compare to python. My goal is just get the int value from digest in C, as I did in python. I tried to use also strtol instead of atoi, but still getting 0 as answer.

*update*
I also want to mention that, my goal is also make modulo with the value by some number let assume 7

For example in python it’s like this:

```
import hashlib
import sys 

Message ="hello world"
integer_value = int.from_bytes(hashlib.sha512(Message.encode()).digest(),sys.byteorder)
Modulo = integer_value % 7
```

Probably I needed to mention that this is why I want to get the integer_value, I might be wrong, If there is better way to get modulo of the digest in C , I would like to know!

Comment: You code doesn't even compile.  It should be `unsigned char digest[512];`, missing include of string.h for `strlen()`, missing `;` after the `SHA512()` call.

Comment: An `int` probably has 32 bits on the system you're using and that can't hold a 512-bit hash value.  Also `atoi()` has no way to return an error, and passing a value to `atoi()` that it can't convert [invokes undefined behavior](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.22.1p1) - a real good reason to **never** use `atoi()` and use `strtol()` instead.  You're not going to be able to treat a SHA-512 hash as a single integer-type value in standard C code - some compilers offer 128-bit integer values, but even those aren't enough.

Comment: Also, I don't see a `SHA512()` macro or funciton in openssl/sha.h but I could be missing something.

Comment: Thank for the help, I fix the code and added some clearance. Sorry for confusion.

Comment: Note that `unsigned char digest[512];` has room for `512 * CHAR_BIT` bits (which is likely 4096 bits) - but you only need room for 512 bits so make it `unsigned char digest[512 / CHAR_BIT];` instead. Also, `unsigned char message[] = "hello world";` should be `char message[] = "hello world";` and you can then cast when calling the digest function instead: `SHA512((const unsigned char*) message, ...`

Answer (score 3):

C doesn't have native 512 bit integer types.

If you want to print the digest then you'll need to print each byte in hex.

```
int i;
for (i=0;i<512/8;i++) {
    if (i!=0) printf(":");
    printf("%02X", digest[i]);
}
printf("\n");
```

Comment: I personally prefer `printf("%02hhX", digest[i]);` to emphasize `digest` is `unsigned char`.  That would also protect against later cut-and-paste copying of the code and use for a `signed char` value resulting in the printing lots of 8-char `FFFFFFxx` values...

Comment: Thank you, is there a way to do modulo with the digest value? Please, I add some clearance.

Comment: @hah In that case you'll need a big number library such as gmp.

Comment: @hah OpenSSL has it's own [bignumber functions](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/man3/bn.html) (for some reason OpenSSL doesn't provide those summary pages for versions later than 1.0.2)

Comment: @dbush , if I can ask please, there is some manipulation that I can do to get the modulo of the digest? Or it’s really complicated?

Comment: @hah Again, you need to use a big number library.  There's one built into OpenSSL, and there's also gmp.

Comment: Okay, I will try, so as i understand, with BN library, I will able to get the value of the digest, after it I can to do modulo

Answer (score 2):

Some of your code is just wrong syntax. e.g.

```
 unsigned char[512] digest;
```

should be:

```
unsigned char digest[512];
```

The array size should probably be `512 / 8` if you want 512 bits.

But you have other problems. I doubt that `SHA512()` gives you a number in ASCII, so using `atoi()` on its output would be pointless.

Also, C does not support 512-bit integers. The size of an integer on most systems is 32 or 64 bits. Handling bigger integers than that requires special libraries.

It's great that higher-level languages can do this stuff in a few lines of code, but to do this in C will take a lot more than that.